# why return reference to ostream object in member function for serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, reference, iostream

//using namespace std;

Here's the following piece of code

```
ostream& write(ostream& os) const {
    os << getRe() << "j " << getIm();
    return os;
}
```

This is a member function in a class representing complex numbers ("PComplex), which is derived from an abstract class ("Serializable"). (Implementation of pure virtual function).

My main question is why do we need to return a reference to an ostream object? Why not void?

Answer (score 1):

Returning an `ostream&` object allows us to chain a bunch of operators togeather.

Consider this statement

```
cout << "Hello " << "World";
```

This is actually two calls to `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const char* c)`.  If we consider the order of execution, we get:

```
(cout << "Hello ") << "World";
```

This function accepts `cout` on the left and `"Hello "` on the right.  It prints the contents of the right hand-side to the console, **then it returns** `cout`.  We we consider what's left after the first step we get this:

```
(cout) << "World";
```

Now we take the brackets away and get:

```
cout << "World;
```

This one is much easier to deal with.  Now we call the function again to print `"World" and return the cout again, which we will simply not do anything with.

---

If we returned `void` instead of `ostream&`, then `(cout << "Hello ")` would reduce to `(void)`.  That would leave us with:

```
(void) << "World";
```

This doesn't match any overloads and so we would then get an error.  While the `(cout << "Hello ")` would still work, we wouldn't be able to chain `<< "World"` on the same line.

Comment: Why don't we just return `os`? If `os` is the reference to `cout` then why again return reference to `os`? Isn't `reference to os` same as `refererence to cout`?